# Select statement that displays a count of every unique variable

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID   |   Value   |   Date
1    |   3000    |   25/06
1    |   3000    |   26/06
1    |   2000    |   12/07
2    |   4000    |   23/12
2    |   4000    |   12/12
3    |   2000    |   01/11
3    |   2000    |   23/04
3    |   4000    |   23/05
3    |   4000    |   04/11
```

Now I want to display unique values for a specific ID and how many times each specific value appears in the table for a specific ID.

The desired output for

`select ### where ID = 1 from tablename; would be:`

```
distinct Value | count
      3000     |   2 
      2000     |   1
```

and for:

`select ### where  ID = 3 from tablename;`

```
distinct Value | count
      2000     |   2 
      4000     |   2
```

Can this be done with a single select statement (for each ID)?

Comment: Yes. Please share what did you try?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
select ID
     , Value
     , Count(*) AS CountOfValues
from tablename
group by ID, Value
```

Just grouping by both ID and Value and counting each amount of times the value appears per those grouping sets.